# How to Secure my Backend API when connecting with Vue based Web Application

Tags: rest, api, vue.js, flask

I am creating a payment gateway integration where merchant can allow user to pay either via card, cryptocurrency or bankwire. I want only my frontend to be able to access the API. One way of doing is that whitelisting IP of my frontend on my flask application which acts as the backend. Any other suggestions to how properly secure the API's as it will transfer really secure information bw the internet

Comment: You can use the jwt token header (https://jwt.io/) for each API request and validate it at flask. Request for jwt token during signing in and then keep it in localstorage. append the jwt authentication in every request header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things here:

- Token based authentication (as Nibin already said)
- CORS on the server side to allow requests coming from your domain name only
- HTTPS